# how to take CSV file input in list of tuples

Tags: csv

I have a .txt(data.txt) file containing csv data like:

```
X         Class
15.0001   Yes
18.00     NO
17.07     Yes
```

I need to make a function to return a list of tuples of each samples. So far I did:

```
import csv
def readAllData(str): 
    with open(str,'r') as f:
        f.readline()
        data=[tuple(line) for line in csv.reader(f)]
    return (data)
```

#### Output:

```
[('15.001\tYES',),
 ('18.00\tNo',),
 ('17.07\tYes',),]
```

#### I want:

```
[(15.001, Yes), (18.00, No), (17.07, Yes)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bring everything into memory at once...

It's won't work for many cases as well..

*csv's* are **,** separated files and *tsv's* are *tab(\t)* separated..
They fall in the same category though..

*tqdm is optional..*

```
import csv
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook

with open('sample.txt','rb') as tsvin, open('new.csv', 'wb') as csvout:

    tsvin = csv.reader(tsvin, delimiter='\t')
    csvout = csv.writer(csvout)

    for row in tqdm_notebook(tsvin):
            csvout.writerows([row[:] for _ in range(2)])
```

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking, you do **not** have a CSV, you have a **TSV**. So I would take the time to split out each row accordingly and then build your tuple.

In the line:

```
data=[tuple(line) for line in csv.reader(f)] return (data)
```

You need to replace `csv.reader` to handle `tsv` instead.

Comment: Can you give a little more explanation on how can I do that?